# Wacom tablet problem with Gimp/GTK applications on Windows

Tags: windows, gimp, gtk, bamboo

I have a Wacom Bamboo tablet with associated pen and mouse. They work fine with most applications except Gimp. I have also noticed problems while using them with other GTK applications on Windows. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Wish i could help you here but it works fine for me... Fernando seems to be on the right track, that option is there in wondows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Windows GTK. As of today there is no solution except to set the mouse to "absolute" mode, which you probably don't want to do for the obvious reason that you want it to behave like a mouse, not a pen.

The defect is:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154657

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried configuring your tablet on Gimp?

I'm using it under Debian GNU/Linux right now. But check if there's an "Input Devices" section in Gimp's preferences, this might be there for the Windows version too. There's an option "Configure extended input devices" for special devices such as tablets.